# React JS: Dynamically replace string in input (live)

Tags: reactjs, components, setstate, date-formatting

An user is able to write data in form of **18/11/2020** [max. 10 chars] in my input.
I want, that anything written is directly sanitized dynamically by a method or rule of mine.
For instance:

> User types a 0 => 00/00/0000 is displayed direct in the label.

For this I have an empty string as default value, but replacing the string with the wanted content didn't work (no changes displayed). Any idea?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState("");

  const handleInput = (date) => {
    const inputValue = date.target.value;
    setState(date.target.value);
    const base = new Date(inputValue);
    
    const dateFormatUsEnglish = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US");
    const dateFormatGerman = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("de-DE");
    const dateParts = dateFormatUsEnglish.formatToParts(base);
 

    const mapped = dateParts.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
      accumulator[currentValue.type] = currentValue.value;
      return accumulator;
    }, {});


    if(inputValue === "0"){ 
   //here should be the method replacing the string with the new one
    }
    if(mapped.month > 12) {
      dateParts[0].value = 12; //set max for month
    }
 
    if(mapped.day > 31) {
      dateParts[2].value = 31; //set max for days
    }
     
    if(mapped.year > 2100) {
      dateParts[4].value = 2100; //set max for year
    }
    if((mapped.year % 2) === 0){

    } //leapyear

    console.log(dateParts); //sliced parts

    console.log(inputValue); //user input
    console.log(base); //dto
    console.log(mapped.month);
    console.log(mapped.day);
    console.log(mapped.year);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input onChange={handleInput} defaultValue={state} maxLength="10" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Assign the necessary converted date format to a state variable and provide it as a value to your input tag

Comment: Could you give me an example, please ?

Answer (score 1):

In formattedDate state variable your necessary date format will be assigned and it will be used as a value for your input

```js
const [state, setState] = useState("");
const [formattedDate, setFormatted] = useState("")

const handleInput = (date) => { 
    //your logic for formatting goes here
    setFormatted(`${formatted.month}/${formatted.day}/${formatted.year}`)
};

return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="text" onChange={handleInput} defaultValue={state} value={formattedDate} maxLength="10" />
    </div>
);
```

Comment: Warning: App contains an input of type undefined with both value and defaultValue props. Input elements must be either controlled or uncontrolled (specify either the value prop, or the defaultValue prop, but not both). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element and remove one of these props. More info: https://reactjs.org/link/controlled-components
    at input
    at div
    at App (https://yltw8.csb.app/src/App.js:24:39)

Comment: Have you provided type="text" in your input tag?